# Call db-specific function from jOOQ

Tags: sqlite, jooq

In the new [`fts5`](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html) virtual tables in SQLite there is a ranking function [`bm25`](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#the_bm25_function). What is the best way to call it from jOOQ? Is there any way to introduce this function as Java/Kotlin function or should it be just a string literal?

What I do currently is

```kotlin
.orderBy(field("bm25(books_fts)"))
```

but indeed this approach is error-prone. I can make a typo in any part and will have an error only in runtime.

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the [plain SQL template](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) directly in your query, better create a custom library for these purposes, e.g.

```kotlin
fun bm25(t: Table<*>): Field<Double> = field("bm25({0})", SQLDataType.DOUBLE, t)
```

Now you can pretend this is a natively supported function in jOOQ and use it in a type safe way everywhere.